# Spotify is not responding to Cortana

Tags: windows-10, cortana, spotify

Spotify doesn't respond to Cortana's requests. After I ask Cortana to play some music on spotify, Cornata successfully opens up Spotify, but doesn't do anything.

Cortana successfully identifies the songs, bands or any other request I made, but Spotify just opens up and doesn't play any song.

I've repaired Cortana using Powershell, reinstalled and relink Spotify to Cortana, but nothing has worked yet. I've also tried unsuccessfully a solution posted on the following link on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0uizERhU70

I thank in advance any help.

Comment: Are you sure that Cortana integration is a feature of Spotify?

Comment: Yes, they are integrated. Spotfify is part of Cortana's music skills. As I explained before, Cortana is able to open Spotify. The problem is that beyond that, spotify doesn't responds to Cortana;s instructions.